# Option to handle Maps v2 keys in gradle file

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-gradle-plugin

Since we need to have 2 maps keys for an application (debug, release), I would like handle them in the gradle file.

Is there an option to put the keys into the gradle file buildVariants and insert a variable in the manifest, that it uses the key depending on the current variant?

If yes, how?

Comment: Write a comment at least, why you're downvoting this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done pretty simply with the build system. You don't need to worry about doing variable substitution in the manifest; the build system's manifest merger can do the work for you.

Set up your project like this:

```
app_module
  +--src
       +--main
            +--AndroidManifest.xml
       +--debug
            +--AndroidManifest.xml
       +--release
            +--AndroidManifest.xml
```

You already have the **src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** file. In this copy, ***remove*** the Google Maps API key `<meta-data>` tag. What you want to do is supply debug- and release-specific versions of this tag in the debug and release manifest files, and let the manifest merger do its thing. In the build-type-specific manifest files, you don't need to supply full manifests with redundant information, but only those parts that will be different. The merger will use the one in **src/main** for the bulk of it:

**src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sbarta.myapplication" >
    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="DEBUG_VALUE"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**src/release/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sbarta.myapplication" >
    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="RELEASE_VALUE"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I had problems first, with that solution, because I forgot to set the application tag. After that it worked. Thanks

Comment: Not working in AS-RC1.  Its not adding the meta-data tags from the release/debug files to the main file.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using gradle you can do the following:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  .. .. ...
    buildTypes {
       debug {
          resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "[YOUR DEV KEY]"
       }
       release {
           resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "[YOUR PROD KEY]"
       }
    }
  }
```

And in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>
```

This way you only have one AndroidManifest.xml and you set value based on your build type. Hope this helps.